# How to write a create table script based on certain column values in Oracle DB?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, create-table

I want to write a create table script based on certain conditions of column values in the Oracle table.

For example I have a table called A and in this table we have 3 columns Country, Country Code and Country Short Name.

If Country column has a value then Country Code and Country Short Name columns may or may not have values.

If Country column not have a value then Country Code and Country Short Name columns have to be mandatory.

[image]

How can I write a create table script for this in Oracle DB?

Comment: Yes you can! Please check the documentation of `create table`, `insert` and `NULL`.

Comment: Creating a table should be a one time thing. Why bother with a script and just create it manually and get it over and done with or is there and underlying problem your trying to solve, which you haven't mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can be done, here's an example with just 2 columns, you can easily expand it to 3 or more:

```
create table tcon (c1 number, c2 number, constraint ck  check ((c1 is not null) or (c1 is null and c2 is not null)));
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it as below, just make sure that the conditions are okay

```
create table tableA (
country varchar2(20),
countryCode varchar2(20),
countryshort varchar2(20),
constraint chk check ((country is null and ( countryCode is not null or countryshort is not null) ) or (country is not null and  (countryCode is null or countryshort is null)))
);
```